# Internet connection problems with ubuntu server VM network

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, dns

so i'm pretty new in networks and wanna test some stuff in a virtual machine first.

I've build a small VM network with Ubuntu Servers. You can look at [network diagramm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0yRa.png) by clicking on this link (ignore the switches, they are only for ilustrational purpose). So basically i wanted to connect two networks with a linux server which is configured as a router. The problem is that now the communication between the internal networks is possible and i can ping for example PC1 and PC2 but i have no internet connection thru the NAT to google or other sides for example.
Using `ping google.com` or `ping 8.8.8.8` puts out the following messages:

> ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

and

> From 192.168.1.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

This happens on every device in the VM network. I've already tested a completely new VM also with the same distribution as well as the same NAT settings and it worked without any problems. I could ping google.com normally. So it's impossible that the Virtual Box settings are causing the problems in my network.

I've created the network in the steps below:

1. I've created every VM with the ubuntu server as the distribution and every VM has a NAT connection with port forwarding for the host access possibility. Also every VM has at least 1 adapter for the internal network. The port forwarding is successful working as expected and i can access every VM with PuTTy on my host PC.
2. I edited the static ips for every machine so that they see eachother. The ips are shown in the network diagramm above. The netplan settings in /etc/netplan for PC1 are listed here:

> ```
> network:
>   ethernets:
>     enp0s3:
>       dhcp4: true
>     enp0s8:
>       dhcp4: no
>       addresses: [192.168.1.11/24]
>       gateway4: 192.168.1.1
>   version: 2
> ```

enp0s3 is the NAT adapter and enp0s8 the internal network adapter.

3. for the router settings i've used 2 ethernet adapters as well as the NAT adapter again. The netplan looks as follow:

> ```
> network:
>   ethernets:
>     enp0s3:
>       dhcp4: true
>     enp0s8:
>       dhcp4: no
>       addresses:
>         - 192.168.1.1/24
>       gateway4: 192.168.1.1
>     enp0s9:
>       dhcp4: no
>       addresses:
>         - 192.168.2.1/24
>       gateway4: 192.168.2.1
>   version: 2
> ```

and i've enabled the ip4 forwarding in /etc/systctl.conf by uncommenting `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` 
That's pretty much it. I'm really frustrated because i've no idea why it's not working right now and spent more than 8 hours searching for it. I'd appreciate every help :) I can also provide more information if needed.

`

---

Hi thank you for your answer!
My PC1 route looks like that:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s8 proto static
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp src 10.0.2.15 metric 100
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15
10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.11
```

I'm not completely sure if it's valid to use two routes for the default source..

The routes of my Router looks like follow:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s8 proto static
default via 192.168.2.1 dev enp0s9 proto static
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp src 10.0.2.15 metric 100
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15
10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.1
192.168.2.0/24 dev enp0s9 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.1
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally setup the VM network for host-only and not NAT?  host-only means that they will only communicate with themselves.  NAT works, but usually gets a different IP address in a different subnet.  Then you have to make sure that port forwarding is enabled in your network settings in your VM.

Comment: Hei ye all ethernet adapters are either in NAT or Internal Network mode. I've nothing setup as a host only adapter

Comment: One other possibility would be to supply your own DNS servers to the `/etc/systemd/resoved.conf` file and then restart the service of `systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service` and see if that helps.

Answer (score -2):

Did you check if you have a default route? I think it's missing.

```
nabil@LAPTOP:~$ ip route
default via 172.30.80.1 dev eth0 -Default route
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.30.80.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.30.85.180
```

Can you check on the PC1 and on the router as well.

On the router Netplan config, could you please comment out the `gateway4` line and do ˋsudo netplan apply` then check if you can ping internet from router. If it works try from the other computer.